# Effect or Affect

Tags: word-choice, differences

I can NEVER teel if it should be effect or affect. What are some ways that help you understand the differance?

Answer (score 1):

First, they're both stressed on the second syllable, so the A or E is pronounced shwa (/ə/), regardless.
I.e, both words are pronounced /ə'fɛkt/.

Second, the word /ə'fɛkt/ that is a verb is spelled with **A**, while the one that is a noun is spelled with **E**. It is not a surprise that they are so similar, since they are related in meaning. What's unusual is spelling them differently this way.

1. *This depression will **affect** my investments.*
2. *This depression will have an **effect** on my investments.*

In (1), *affect* is a verb; in (2), *effect* is a noun, part of the idiom *`have ___ effect on`*,
which means the same thing as *affect*.

Third, there are also two other -- rare, and normally idiomatic -- uses of the spellings *affect* and effect,
but they're easy to distinguish from the normal ones described above.

One, the noun *affect*, is stressed on the first syllable, so that the vowel is not reduced to shwa, but rather fully pronounced: /'æafɛkt/. It also has a very restricted meaning, as a clinical technical term for display of emotion.

- *He has very low **affect**; pay attention or you might miss something important.*

The other use, the verb *effect*, usually has a secondary stress on the first syllable, so that the vowel is often if not always /i/, and not shwa. In meaning, it also has a limited distribution, being always transitive, and used mainly in the idioms *effect an escape, effect a solution,* and the like. It's archaic and somewhat formal, the sort of thing that shows up in 19th-century newspapers and court proceedings.

- *The burglar **effected** his escape by means of the bathroom window*.

Nowadays we would use the verb *escape* instead of having to use *effect* or something similar.